# PhP returning Json in []

Tags: php, json

Hey I am trying to pass data back in json format using `json_encode`.

However it seems to return like this:

```
[{‘county’:’us’,’sector’:’retail’}]
```

However the end user has said that they expect the response without the square brackets.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: share your code how you are generating json?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the array you're trying to output? Also fun fact, having an array as the first layer of a json is exploitable. [OWASP link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Always_return_JSON_with_an_Object_on_the_outside)

Comment: With `’`? Really? I can't think of any time that `json_encode` would do that. You also failed to include a [mcve]. We can't solve a problem with code you haven't shown us.

Comment: `json_encode($data[0])` will give you the first object. What you have is an array, you are looking for a single object.

Comment: The purpose of this is to return data as an api via a post request. How would be the best way to return this then?

Comment: @Quentin Actually the `‘` were added by the editor. Check the history.

Comment: @Andrew — I looked at the history. The only change to that line was indenting it to make it as code.

Comment: Yeep, you're correct. I'm in need of a pair of glasses I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you are generating the value you encode... `json_encode` has an option `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` you could use but from what I can see that's probably not what you want, as it seems to me this would only turn the "square brackets" into a wrapper object. Nevertheless, if you'd like to try:

```
json_encode($value, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Edit: as others have said, it seems likely `json_encode($value[0])` is what you want.

Comment: Perfect the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT seems to have done the trick thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is:

```
$data = [
    'country' => 'us',
    'sector' => 'retail',
];
```

Then just return a json_encoded array like so:

```
json_encode($data);
// {"country":"us","sector":"retail"}
```

However, if your array with data is "nested" like so:

```
$data = [[
    'country' => 'us',
    'sector' => 'retail',
]];
```

then return the encoded first element of it:

```
json_encode($data[0]);
// {"country":"us","sector":"retail"}
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience of this happening is that you're accidentally storing your data as the first item of an array.

For example you may have done:

```
$json_store = Array();
$json_store[] = Array('country' => 'us', 'sector' => 'retail');
$json = json_encode($json_store);
```

A way of testing for this is to see if doing the following removes the brackets:

```
$json_encode($json_store[0])
```

If it does, you've a unnecessarily nested array that you should fix. Using the above line probably should be avoided as it's better to fix how the data is stored in the first place.